# Tkinter: Is it possible to change the stacking order of placed Frames?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been experimenting with Frames placed in the root window. As far as I can see, the stacking order is determined when the frames are created, the
ones created first being below the ones created later. The order of .place
does not seem to have any effect.

Is there some way of changing the stacking order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably looking for:

```
widget.lift()          # move to the top of the stack
widget.lift(another)   # move to just above another widget
widget.lower()         # move to the bottom of the stack
widget.lower(another)  # move to just below another widget
```

Explained [here](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html). (This is the best documentation I can find. If you read [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#widget.Widget.lift-method), it reads like `lift` and `lower` only apply to windows, but in fact they also work with other widgets.)

Comment: Note there is a bug in tkinter that prevents `lift` from working on canvas widgets. To get around the bug see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55559387/6929343).