# In tkinter, is there a way to change the draw stack order of overlapping canvases?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

### The Problem

Using Python's tkinter, I'm trying to create custom buttons and other widgets by extending the [Canvas widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#when-to-use). How can I change which custom canvas widgets get drawn on top as the user interacts with them?

[lift()](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.lift-method) works for regular tkinter Buttons and other widgets, but raises an error when I try to use it to lift a Canvas, because [Canvas has its own lift() method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.lift-method). Canvas's lift() is deprecated for Canvas in favor of tag_raise(). However, [tag_raise()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.tag_raise-method) documentation says it "doesn’t work with window items", which fits my experience, and directs me to use lift() instead. My brain chased this seemingly circular documentation until it raised its own kind of StackOverflow exception, which brings me to ask you.

### Code Illustration

Here's some basic code that runs and illustrates my problem. I've included button3, a regular button that can lift() as expected. If I click on custom_button1, however, the click_handler raises an exception.

```
from tkinter import Button, Canvas, Frame, Tk
from tkinter.constants import NW

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=200, height=200, background="black")
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.button3 = Button(self.canvas, text="button3")
        self.custom_button1 = MyCustomButton(self.canvas)
        self.custom_button2 = MyCustomButton(self.canvas)

        self.canvas.create_window(20, 20, anchor=NW, window=self.button3)
        self.canvas.create_window(40, 40, anchor=NW, window=self.custom_button1)
        self.canvas.create_window(34, 34, anchor=NW, window=self.custom_button2)

        self.button3.bind("<Button-1>", self.click_handler)
        self.custom_button1.bind("<Button-1>", self.click_handler)
        self.custom_button2.bind("<Button-1>", self.click_handler)


    def click_handler(self,event):
        event.widget.lift() #raises exception if event.widget is a MyCustomButton
                            #note that Canvas.lift() is deprecated, but documentation
                            #says Canvas.tag_raise() doesn't work with window items

class MyCustomButton(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, width=40, height=25, background='blue')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

This works for as desired for button3, but for custom_button1, the exception that is raised is:

```
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!example.!canvas.!mycustombutton2 raise tagOrId ?aboveThis?"
```

That exception makes sense in the context that Canvas.lift() and Canvas.tag_raise() are normally used to affect an item on the canvas by tag or id, not the canvas itself. I just don't know what to do about changing the stack order of the canvas itself so I can use it as a custom widget.

### A Work-Around I've Considered

I could manage a bunch of custom widgets on a canvas by only having *one* canvas that handles *all* drawing and *all* the mouse events for *all* the widgets. I could still have classes for the widgets, but instead of inheriting from Canvas, they'd accept Canvas parameters. So adding would look something like the code below, and I'd have to write similar code for lifting, moving, determining if a click event applied to this button, changing active state, and so forth.

```
def add_to_canvas(self, canvas, offset_x=0, offset_y=0):

        self.button_border = canvas.create_rectangle(
                                        offset_x + 0, offset_y + 0,
                                        offset_x + 40, offset_y + 25
                                        )

        #create additional button features
```

This work-around seems to go against established coding paradigms in tkinter, though. Furthermore, I believe this approach would prevent me from drawing these custom buttons above other window objects. (According to the [create_window() documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_window-method) "You cannot draw other canvas items on top of a widget." In this work-around, all the custom buttons would be canvas items, and so if I'm reading this correctly, couldn't be drawn on top of other widgets.) Not to mention the extra code it would take to implement. That said, I don't currently have a better idea of how to implement this.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: using `if isinstance(event.widget, Canvas):` you can recognize if  you clicked `Canvas` or other widget (ie. `Button`) and use different methods

Comment: @furas True, but I wasn't sure what different method to use instead of lift(). Thankfully, Bryan Oakley's answer addresses my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you've stumbled on a bug in the tkinter implementation. You can work around this in a couple of ways. You can create a method that does what the tkinter `lift` method does, or you can directly call the method in the tkinter `Misc` class.

Since you are creating your own class, you can override the `lift` method to use either of these methods.

Here's how you do it using the existing function. Be sure to import `Misc` from tkinter:

```
from tkinter import Misc
...
class MyCustomButton(Canvas):
    ...
    def lift(self, aboveThis=None):
        Misc.tkraise(self)
```

Here's how  you directly call the underlying tk interpreter:

```
class MyCustomButton(Canvas):
    ...
    def lift(self, aboveThis=None):
        self.tk.call('raise', self._w, aboveThis)
```

With that, you can raise one button over the other by calling the `lift` method:

```
def click_handler(self,event):
    event.widget.lift()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Both options you give work for me. Is there one I should favor over the other? I assume Misc.tkraise() is preferred since it doesn't rely on the private variable _w, but I'm new enough to Python that I'm not sure.

Comment: @SansWit: I would personally use the second method.