# In Python Tkinter: How do I overlap a ".place()"ed widget over another ".place()"ed widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, display

I've been searching for a way to put widget1, which was created first, over widget2. I just want widget1 to be displayed over widget2 without changing the order that they are created. If it makes a significant difference, I wish to do this with both widgets sharing a parent canvas

Comment: That's what `.tkraise()`/`.lower()` are for.

Comment: ^ I got the following error:    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2937, in tag_raise
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'raise') + args)
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!canvas.!canvas17 raise tagOrId ?aboveThis?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55559387/7432

Comment: ^ It seams like this is an bug with Tkinter. It seams like the only solution is to make my own function that does what I want